# Display other than English language in testdata.properties file

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, selenium, application.properties

I’m using testdata.properties file to pass values into my selenium test scripts.  When I enter

```
Chinese Charachter : 成長促進

japanese Charachter :`へのコミットメント
```

in testdata.properties file it is displaying as

```
chinese charachter :: \u6210\u9577\u4FC3\u9032

japanese charachter :: \u3078\u306E\u30B3\u30DF\u30C3\u30C8\u30E1\u30F3\u30C8
```

Please let me know how to display text in Japanese language in testdata.properties file?

Answer (score 2):

By default encoding provide is eclipse is **"ISO 8859-1 encoding"** so when you paste any native language code like you paste Chinese and japanese it will default converted it into **nativeToAscii** encoding.

There is need to change **"ISO 8859-1 encoding"** to **"UTF-8"** in your eclipse.

**Go-to Eclipse - Windows - Preferences - Search for the content Type**

[image]

Now change that Encoding to **"UTF-8"** and it will show your properties file in native language. First update your encoding and than do apply and close.

[image]

[image]

When you set your data **"ISO 8859-1 encoding"** and when you use sendkeys it will automatically send data through native language.

refer below code snippet.

```
package com.software.testing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Testingclass extends DriverFactory {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\eclipse-workspace\\SoftwareTesting\\testdata.properties");
        FileInputStream fileInput = null;
        try {
            fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        // load properties file
        try {
            prop.load(fileInput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='Search']")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("japanese"));
        //driver.findElement(By.id("q")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("chinese"));
    }
}
```

Comment: HI @Dhru 'soni - After updating to UTF-8, values are not properly reading with below code from testdata.properties file. Please help me                                                                                                    FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java" + "/config/config.properties");
// prop.load(new InputStreamReader(ip, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
// prop.load(new InputStreamReader(ip, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")));
prop.load(ip);

Comment: @arkadiyala you don't require to use // prop.load(new InputStreamReader(ip, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));  if you set your encoding "ISO 8859-1" when you copy data in your test data in your properties file it will store at ascii but when you use send key it will automatically send it into native language. you can refer my updated answer.

Comment: HI @Dhru 'soni - Thanks for your help!! .  When I set data "ISO 8859-1 encoding" , sendkey is sending data through native language and script is working fine, but testdata.properties is not in human readable format. Is there any way i can achieve both (.properties in human readable format + senkeys sends data through native language )